# How to restore deleted github history

Tags: git, github

How do we restore a deleted github history? I accidentally deleted them all and trying to restore 'em all back. Anyone who experienced the same please?

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674226/does-github-keep-deleted-remote-branches-in-history-if-so-can-those-be-restore

Comment: What 'history' and how did you 'delete' it?

Comment: Have you deleted the repository or just the files?

Comment: i deleted just files

Comment: Which files? In the working directory? That wouldn't affect history.